# Laravel FullCalendar

Tags: php, laravel, date

I am doing a reservation system ... and I am having the following problems:

People can book for example from 11/06/2020 - 10:00 to 11:00 am ... registered this ... the second client cannot register for example from 11/06/2020 - 10:30 to 11:30 (since it is busy) so far everything is perfect ...

Problem 1) But if the reservation is from 11/06/2020 -
10:00 a.m. to 11:00 a.m. ... does not allow a client to register from 11/06/2020 - 11:00 a.m. to 12:00 p.m. ... they must do so from 11/06/2020 - 11:01 a.m. to 12:00 p.m. ...

Problem 2) if a customer registers 11/06/2020 - 11:00 to 12:00

it lets me register 11/06/2020 - 1:00 p.m. to 3:00 p.m. for example but not ...

11/07/2020 - 11:00 to 12:00

He says the schedule is already busy, but he's not comparing the day to me ...

```
public function validarFecha($fecha, $horaInicial, $horaFinal)
    {
        $agenda = Booking::select("*")
            ->whereDate('day', $fecha)
            ->whereBetween('hour_start', [$horaInicial, $horaFinal])
            ->orWhereBetween('hour_end', [$horaInicial, $horaFinal])
            ->first();

            return $agenda == null ? true : false;
    } 

-----------------------------

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        if($this->validarFecha($input["txtFechaInicio"], $input["txtHoraInicio"], $input["txtHoraFinal"])){
            $agenda = Booking::create([
                "id_user"=>$input["ddlUsuarios"],
                "day"=>$input["txtFechaInicio"],
                "hour_start"=>$input["txtHoraInicio"],
                "hour_end"=>$input["txtHoraFinal"],
                "observation"=>$input["txtDescripcion"]
            ]);

            return response()->json(["ok"=>true]);
        }else{
            return response()->json(["ok"=>false]);
        }

        dd($input);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an additional comparison in your ternary to determine if `$horaInicial` matches `$agenda->hour_end` where you return false, something like:

```
return $agenda === null || $agenda->hour_end === $horaInicial
```

As long as no agenda exists, or the end of the agenda matches the beginning of the agenda, then we will have a `valid` start time.

Comment: Good problem one solved !! it works!  Problem 2 persist.

Thanks you!